# How can I register a specific version of a Delta Table in Azure Machine Learning Studio from Azure ADLS Gen 1?

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, registration, retention

I created a Delta Table in ADLS Gen 1 with the following code in Databricks:

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("db.my_tbl", path ='adl://organisation.azuredatalakestore.net/folder_name/my_data')
```

Sometimes, I re-run the code above to generate a new version of the `my_tbl` table. As usual with delta tables, a history is build and it must regulary be optimized and vaccumed. Now, I am often retraining a ML Model in Azure Machine Learning Studio and am wondering if it possible to register a specific version of the delta table?

Currently, even after vaccuming, all my delta files (including older versions) are registered in Azure ML Studio when reading the parquet files from `my_data` folder! That is because I can not lower the retention period of the delta table below 168h except turning of `spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled`. I do not want to turn it off.

I register my dataset through the ML Studio Interface as a File Dataset (not Tabular Dataset). This registration looks like this:

[image]

Right now I see only the option to create a copy of `my_data` and reading it instead. Is there another way? Do you know if I can specify something in the path to point to the "right" .parquet files (belonging to a specific delta table version)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Databricks and don't mind some workaround when moving folders, here is a solution based on [manifest files](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-generate.html). This script lists all files of your LATEST delta table version. It can be used for pipelines with incremental data updates.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.symlinkFormatManifest.fileSystemCheck.enabled", False) # this type of filesystemcheck is an AWS feature currently, so it needs to be disabled on Azure or Google Cloud

from delta.tables import DeltaTable

delta_path=<'full path in data lake pointing to your table'> # note your Databricks workspace needs WRITE access for the data lake!

newpath=<'folder outside delta table'>

delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, f"{delta_path}")

#clean up existing folder to be on the safe side 
dbutils.fs.rm(f"{newpath}/_symlink_format_manifest", recurse=True)

manifest = delta_table.generate("symlink_format_manifest")

# The automatically created symlink folder needs to be moved out from the delta path!
# Otherwise spark import will not recognize the format, as a usual delta table is expected under this path. The symlink_format_manifest is not a correct delta table partition!

dbutils.fs.mv(f"{delta_path}/_symlink_format_manifest", f"{newpath}/_symlink_format_manifest", recurse=True)

# create the list of parquet files from the manifest
filelist=spark.read.text(f"{newpath}/_symlink_format_manifest/*").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

filelist
```